# How specific should I talk about my papers and projects in my personal statement for grad school?

Tags: graduate-admissions, statement-of-purpose

I am applying for grad school and during my undergraduate studies I have some projects and papers. How detailed should I talk about these projects in my personal statement? Should it be like an abstract or is that even too detailed? Or should I provide only the motivation and results of the project?